# Prevent direct JSON posting with Fiddler/Postman

Tags: .net, json, security, single-page-application

I developed my first SPA and after basking in all the glory that came with it, a sudden shock of terror came upon me.  What is to prevent a user, authenticated with a json web token, from using fiddler or postman and POST'ing something like this?

```
{ ApplicationId: 1000, "BillableAmount" : .01 }
```

I say "authenticated with a web token" because they could just grab their current token and use that from within fiddler/postman.  My concern is not just the BillableAmount, but any sensitive data.

What if the user "owns" ApplicationId 1000 & 1001 and they fiddler ApplicationId 1000's data into ApplicationId 1001 - or worse yet someone else's application?

Is there any way to prevent this type of scenario without resorting to numerous server-side checks such as "does the user own this application and was it the one that was originally sent?"

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely need server side checks. To not have them would be highly irresponsible.

You may also want to look at methods of limiting cross site request forgery (XSRF), to prevent third party actors from trying to exploit what you have described.

You do also have server side validation running, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I went through great pains to put server side protection into place which is why I wrote this post.  I investigated using the .NET AntiForgeryToken, but that wouldn't be a silver bullet here since the AntiForgeryToken could be reused. I just feel like I'm reinventing the wheel with some of these checks (such as making sure the primary key of the data isn't modified from what was sent down).

Comment: David, my first assumption is you're asking the wrong question. You should be showing your code and asking for feedback, and then describing how you see things working. Instead we only have the latter. I've upvoted Paddy's answer because I believe he correctly answers your question as posted.